# Firefox remembers logins but they are not stored in Saved Logins

Tags: firefox, login, skype

I have just gone to [www.skype.com](http://www.skype.com) in my FF 60 (the last time I did it was several reboots ago), and it turns out that FF automatically entered my account, so it remembered my username and password.

But if I check my Saved Logins, there is no Skype there.

**How can this be explained?**

Option 1:
There is a checkbox during login for *Keep me logged in* or the like and I checked it.
I did not use that option.

Comment: You may have selected `Keep me signed in` option during login process.

Comment: @Sandeep - It might have been a possibility. But I have just logged out and logged in again, and it did not ask for such option.

Answer (score 0):

The actual login page is https://login.live.com, that is the domain for which FF Saved Logins remembers the password.

I probably closed FF without signing out, and then when visiting again www.skype.com it tried logging in. I guess that without having the password remembered for https://login.live.com, it would not log in automatically.